# Async write to PassThrough stream

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I need to read a wav file into memory, and pipe it repeatedly to `node-speaker`. The following code attempts to do this, but **the sound only plays once**. Why is this?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')
const { Reader } = require('wav')
const Speaker = require('speaker')

fs.readFile('sample.wav', (e, buffer) => {

  const speaker = new Speaker()
  const reader = new Reader()
  const pass = new PassThrough()

  reader.pipe(speaker)
  pass.pipe(reader)

  setInterval(() => {
    pass.write(buffer)
  }, 1000)

})
```

Additionally, if two play events happen in quick succession, I'd like to cut-off the original as soon as the new event occurs.

**UPDATE**

I've made some progress with this. The following code now plays the sample repeatedly, but every time it writes `speaker error: write() failed: 2556` and the sample is cut short.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { Reader } = require('wav')
const Speaker = require('speaker')

const chunks = []
const reader = new Reader()
const speaker = new Speaker()
const file = fs.createReadStream('sample.wav')

file.pipe(reader)
reader.on('data', c => chunks.push(c))

speaker.on('error', e => console.log(`speaker error: ${e.message}`))
reader.on('error', e => console.log(`reader error: ${e.message}`))

reader.on('end', () => {

  const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)

  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('writing')
    speaker.write(buffer)
  }, 1000)

})
```